# Why doesn't XCOPY copy my junctions?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, ntfs, symbolic-link, junction

I'm trying to copy a Users Directory with XCOPY, but parts of it are not working.

*(I'm running as Administrator, in a command prompt which was started with **Run As Administrator**)*

The user directory looks like: *(abbreviated)*

```
> dir /a /q
05/18/2014  05:42 PM    <DIR>          MyPC\JoeBob            AppData
05/18/2014  05:42 PM    <JUNCTION>     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    Application Data [C:\Users\JoeBob\AppData\Roaming]
05/18/2014  05:42 PM    <DIR>          MyPC\JoeBob            Contacts
05/18/2014  05:42 PM    <JUNCTION>     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    Cookies [C:\Users\JoeBob\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Cookies]
05/18/2014  05:42 PM    <JUNCTION>     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    Local Settings [C:\Users\JoeBob\AppData\Local]
05/18/2014  05:42 PM    <DIR>          MyPC\JoeBob            Music
05/18/2014  05:42 PM    <JUNCTION>     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    My Documents [C:\Users\JoeBob\Documents]
05/18/2014  05:42 PM    <JUNCTION>     NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    NetHood [C:\Users\JoeBob\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Network Shortcuts]
05/18/2014  09:31 PM           786,432 MyPC\JoeBob            NTUSER.DAT
05/18/2014  09:31 PM           262,144 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    ntuser.dat.LOG1
05/18/2014  05:42 PM                 0 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    ntuser.dat.LOG2
05/18/2014  09:31 PM            65,536 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TM.blf
05/18/2014  09:31 PM           524,288 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TMContainer00000000000000000001.regtrans-ms
05/18/2014  09:31 PM           524,288 NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM    NTUSER.DAT{016888bd-6c6f-11de-8d1d-001e0bcde3ec}.TMContainer00000000000000000002.regtrans-ms
```

Note that:

- Some of the directories are really junctions (aka. symlinks / reparse points)
- The junctions have owner `NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM`.

When I run the command:

```
xcopy C:\Users\JoeBob\*.* E: /O/X/E/H/K/B
```

the various switches are supposed to do:

- `/O` - Copy Ownership info
- `/B` - Copy Symlink

But when I actually do the copy, and view the results at the destination **E:**, all the Junctions have become real directories, and have owner `BUILTIN\Administrators`

It seems that switches `/O` and `/B` both failed.
But I cannot find any mention that those switches don't work for SYSTEM-owned junctions.

Am I missing something? Is there a good fix or workaround for this?

Comment: Note that Run as Administrator is not the same as Run as System. I can't answer with certaincy why this is failing, but I would assume it is due to it being owned by SYSTEM.

Comment: Nope:  I changed the owner of one of the Junctions to be my Admin-user, and repeated the copy: The junction still became a Directory, and still had owner `BUILTIN\Administrators`

Comment: "junctions (aka. symlinks / reparse points)" Those are not the same thing.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think your mixing a `directory Symbolic link` with `directory Junction`.

A directory Junction is very different from a directory symbolic link (Symlink). `XCOPY` **does** copy Symlinks correctly (with `/B`) but it can't handle directory Junctions. (See an [explanation of all these types here](http://devtidbits.com/2009/09/07/windows-file-junctions-symbolic-links-and-hard-links/))

You can copy the directory with Robocopy and exclude the directory Junctions (with `/XJ`) but then you don't have those junctions in your backup. You could Google for it: [windows copy junction points](https://www.google.com/search?q=windows+copy+junction+points).

This way i found [this topic](https://serverfault.com/questions/304924/how-to-copy-junction-points-on-windows-xp) with a possible solution of using the tool [FastCopy](http://ipmsg.org/tools/fastcopy.html.en) which would preserve the junction points.